# pyodbc query truncating variable strings, but not when directly executed (Impala)

Tags: sql, python-3.x, pyodbc, impala, hue

I have a dataframe like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [['quite_long_string_1', 'abcdefghijk_1'],
    ['quite_long_string_2', 'abcdefghijk_2'],
    ['quite_long_string_3', 'abcdefghijk_3']],
    columns=["col1", "col2"]
)
```

My connection is made via pyodbc, and the querying is like so:

```
string = "INSERT INTO {0}.{1}(col1, col2) VALUES (CAST(? AS VARCHAR(255)), CAST(? AS VARCHAR(255)))".format(lab, table)
with conn.cursor() as cursor:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        cursor.execute(string, (row["col1"], row["col2"]))
    cursor.commit()
```

After running this, I go into my table via Hue and the data looks like this:

```
quite_lo abcdefg
quite_lo abcdefg
```

Now when I go directly via Hue (Impala) with the string:

```
INSERT INTO mylab.mytable(col1, col2) VALUES (CAST('quite_long_string_1' AS VARCHAR(255)), CAST('abcdefghijk_1' AS VARCHAR(255)))
```

the full strings are shown as normal/expected. Why does this work for one and not the other? No error message is thrown, just the first 7 characters are displayed only when I insert via the pyodbc library. I'm on Windows 7 Enterprise.

For the connection I have:

```
try:
    conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=mydsn', autocommit=True)
    conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
    conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
    conn.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
except pyodbc.Error as e:
    logger.debug("Hadoop connection error: {0}\n".format(e))
```

And using `SELECT version()` gives `impalad version 2.12.0-cdh5.15.1 RELEASE ...`

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: @Gord Thompson: Windows 7 Enterprise

Comment: Try setting the pyodbc character encoding to UTF-8 as described [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode#mysql-and-postgresql).

Comment: @GordThompson: I tried the suggestions (see please updated post giving my connection), but unfortunately there was no change either.

Comment: Try running [this VBScript](https://pastebin.com/EPZHS7CP) and see if it works any better. If not, then pyodbc isn't the problem.